# For loop display radio buttons with first one checked

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, radio-button

I have a for loop that displays radio buttons and I want the first one to display as checked. But when I put a if statement inside the for loop for this the page nevers loads. Any ideas?

```
$mains = array(0=>'Beef Steak', 1=>'Chicken Breast', 2=>'Pork Chops');
$mainscount = count($mains);

<?php for ($mainNO = 0; $mainNO < $mainscount; $mainNO++) { ?>
  <label for="mains<?php echo $mainNO ?>" class="radiobutton"><?php echo $mains[$mainNO]; ?></label>
  <input type="radio" name="mains" id="mains<?php echo $mainNO; ?>" value="<?php echo $mainNO; ?>" 
  <?php if($mainNO = 0){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php for ($mainNO = 0; $mainNO < $mainscount; $mainNO++) { ?>
    <label for="mains<?php echo $mainNO ?>" class="radiobutton"><?php echo $mains[$mainNO]; ?></label>
    <input type="radio" name="mains" id="mains<?php echo $mainNO; ?>" value="<?php echo $mainNO; ?>"
        <?php if ($mainNO == 0) {
            echo ' checked="checked" ';
        } ?>/>
<?php } ?>
```

you use `=` where you should use `==`

Answer (score 0):

u are using assingment operator in comparision statement

```
<?php for ($mainNO = 0; $mainNO < $mainscount; $mainNO++) { ?>
<label for="mains<?php echo $mainNO ?>" class="radiobutton"><?php echo $mains[$mainNO]; ?></label>
<input type="radio" name="mains" id="mains<?php echo $mainNO; ?>" value="<?php echo $mainNO; ?>"
    <?php if ($mainNO == 0) {
        echo " checked";
    } ?>/>
```

and in HTML5 you can use **checked** only

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

**// Note: You used single = in if condition that is wrong, it will create indefinite loop . Tested code.**

```
    $mains = array(0=>'Beef Steak', 1=>'Chicken Breast', 2=>'Pork Chops');
    $mainscount = count($mains);

     for ($mainNO = 0; $mainNO < $mainscount; $mainNO++) { 

        // Checked if value is 0
        if($mainNO == 0){  $checked = 'checked="checked"'; }else { $checked =''; };

        echo "<label for='mains".$mainNO."' class='radiobutton'>".$mains[$mainNO]."</label>";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='mains' id='mains".$mainNO."' value='".$mainNO."' $checked   />";


    }
```